# Pass a Mono to non-reactive method

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am trying to use the result of a Mono as a parameter to a non-reactive method.  Specifically the value of a service method returning a Mono in the .uri() portion of a WebClient.get() request.

**Scenario**

User requests the URLs for product image based on the name of the product.  The API that resolves the image URLs uses the product id not product name.
In an imperative app I would lookup the productId, build a .uri() and execute the WebClient request.

I've shown my three attempts below.

Any pointers or examples that could help me understand how to accomplish this in a declarative / reactive way?

**Service Interface**

```
@Service
public class ProductService {
    public Mono<Long> lookupProductId(String name)
}
```

**Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("product")
public class ProductController {
    @GetMapping("/{name}/imageUrl")
    public Flux<String> getProductImages(@PathVariable("name") String name) {
        // format of correct product URL:
            // https://myapp.com/latest/products/XXXXXXXX/imageUrl/?datasource=production
        
        String baseUri = "https://myapp.com/latest/products";
        String dataUri = "/imageUrl/";
        String sourceUri = "/?datasource=production";
        
        WebClient otherWebClient = WebClient.builder().baseUrl(baseUri).build();

    // attempt 1
        return otherWebClient.get()
                .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("/").build(
                    dataUri, 
                    // How to get the product id here?
                        productService.lookupProductId(name).subscribe(),
                    sourceUri))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(String.class);
    
    // attempt 2
        return productService.lookupProductId(name)
            .map(productNumber -> {
                System.out.println(productNumber.toString());   // correct product number is printed here
                otherWebClient.get()
                    .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("/").build(
                        dataUri, 
                        // How to get the product id here?
                        productNumber.toString();
                        sourceUri))
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToFlux(String.class);
            });     
            
    // attempt 3 doesn't even compile
        return Flux.zip(productService.lookupProductId(name),
                otherWebClient.get()
                    .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("/").build(
                        dataUri, 
                        // How to get the product id here?
                        ????????
                        sourceUri))
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToFlux(String.class));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*attempt 2* looks good, except the semicolon which I guess is a typo. But since it creates a new Publisher (Flux in your case) you need to use `flatMap` instead of `map`. Or `flatMapMany` if you need multiple results from a Mono. In you case you have just a single HTTP GET so it supposed to be just a `flatMap` with `bodyToMono` processing of the result.

So it should be:

```
return productService.lookupProductId(name)
        .flatMap(productNumber -> 
            otherWebClient.get()
                .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("/").build(
                    dataUri, 
                    productNumber.toString(),
                    sourceUri))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
        );
```

Comment: I tried flatMap but complier error - Incompatible types. Found: 'reactor.core.publisher.Mono<java.lang.Object>', required: 'reactor.core.publisher.Flux<java.lang.String>'

If I change the method to return a Mono<Object> then complier error no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that Flux<T> conforms to Mono<? extends R>

Any ideas on cause of type mismatch?

Comment: Ah, yes, if you need mupliple results it's `flatMapMany` (though it's strange why do  multiple, since it's just a single http request). For casting please double check

Comment: Thanks for the answer and clarifications!!
The result has multiple  URLs so I thought I would need a Flux, turns out a Mono produces the same result.  I changed the method to return a Mono and stayed with flatMap.